# Are Unowned references set to 'nil' when deinitialized?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

I'm confused on this topic in swift where it is said that unowned references must always have a value and cannot be optional, also meaning they cannot be set to 'nil'....well I just saw a program on the Apple documents for swift that instance 'A' with an unowned reference to instance 'B' was deinitialized and deallocated right after instance 'B' was deinitialized/deallocated......when a var is deinitialzed/dealloc doesn't it mean they are set to 'nil'??? Instance B is an optional so sure it can hold 'nil' but why did instance 'A' get deinitialized when its supposed to always have a value????

PS: If this helps..... instance 'B' was an optional type with a strong reference to instance 'A'

Comment: This is very hard to explain if you don't have prior knowledge about memory management in a language with less abstractions, say C or Pascal. It all boils down to the definition of pointers and their abstraction as object references.

Answer (score 2):

An object is deinitialized when its strong reference count drops to 0, but it is not deallocated until its weak reference count also drops to zero.

"Deinitializing" an object means that its `deinit` function is executed if it has one, releasing any resource that it holds, and clearing any references that it may have (potentially deinitializing and deallocating more objects). "Deallocating" is when the memory is reclaimed by the runtime. A deinitialized object's reference counting header is still valid.

When you access a `weak` reference, the Swift runtime ensures that the object is still in an initialized state. If it isn't, the weak reference is set to `nil` and the deinitialized object's weak reference count is decremented.

Unowned references also count towards the weak reference count. When you access an unowned reference, the Swift runtime also ensures that the object is in an initialized state; but if it is not, instead of clearing the reference (it can't do that because it is not optional), it crashes your program.

This effectively makes an unowned reference behave like an implicitly-unwrapped optional, whereas a weak reference behaves like an optional.

The tradeoff for self-zeroing weak references and clean-crashing unowned references is that an object's backing memory cannot be reclaimed until all of its weak references have been tested or deinitialized, and until all of its unowned references have been deinitialized.

Source: [Swift runtime code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/HeapObject.cpp)

Answer (score 1):

The point of an `unowned` reference is to hold a weak reference to something that you are guaranteeing (based on your application logic) will not be deallocated prior to the object that has the `unowned` reference.  You can [read more in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID54).

In a sense it is a similar thing to an implicitly unwrapped optional type (such as `String!`).  You're telling the compiler that you won't ever access the value when it is `nil`, and if you do your program will crash.

Comment: well isn't a variable deinitialized and deallocated when set to `nil` ? So what do you mean by "won't ever access the value when it is `nil` ? It isn't accessible anyway because it gets deallocated when set to nil anyway.....correct?

Comment: If the object the variable points to is deallocated, the variable is not set to `nil` (this is what a weak reference does) and the program will crash if you access it.

Answer (score 0):

It is meaningless to talk about what an `unowned` variable "holds" after the object it points to has been deallocated, because Swift *[guarantees](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID54)* that your app will crash if you ever try to access the variable after the object it points to has been deallocated:

> Note also that Swift guarantees your app will crash if you try to
>   access an unowned reference after the instance it references is
>   deallocated. You will never encounter unexpected behavior in this
>   situation. Your app will always crash reliably, although you should,
>   of course, prevent it from doing so.

Comment: It will also crash *while the deinitializer* is still running, which surprised me.

Comment: @Raphael: Well, in Objective-C ARC, weak variables are set to nil when the object they point to starts deallocation, so I guess what you're describing is consistent with that.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, if you use the unowned keyword to define a reference to an object, and that object is deallocated before you try to access it, the application will crash. Therefore, it is crucial to carefully determine where you use unowned references. On the other hand, if you are uncertain whether the object will be deallocated, you can use the weak keyword instead, which will automatically set the reference to nil if the object is deallocated.

So in summary:

-> Use unowned when you are certain that the referenced object will be available throughout its   lifetime.

-> Use weak when you are unsure whether the referenced object will be deallocated.

By using the appropriate keyword, you can avoid crashes caused by accessing deallocated objects in your Swift applications.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?