# Safety of unowned in swift

Tags: swift

I was reading about `unowned` from the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

> Like weak references, an unowned reference does not keep a strong hold
>   on the instance it refers to. Unlike a weak reference, however, an
>   unowned reference is assumed to always have a value. Because of this,
>   an unowned reference is always defined as a nonoptional type.

So it seems unowned are similar to weak but they are non optionals.

I was wondering what will happen if when the referenced unowned is deallocated. Why is there no checks like optionals.

I mean I can do something like this,

```
class Customer {
    let name: String
    var card: CreditCard?
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    deinit { print("\(name) is being deinitialized") }
}

class CreditCard {
    let number: UInt64
    unowned let customer: Customer
    init(number: UInt64, customer: Customer) {
        self.number = number
        self.customer = customer
    }
    deinit { print("Card #\(number) is being deinitialized") }
}

var card: CreditCard? = nil
do {
    var john: Customer
    john = Customer(name: "John Appleseed")
    john.card = CreditCard(number: 1234_5678_9012_3456, customer: john)
    card = john.card
}

print("Card belongs to \(card?.customer.name)")
```

In the last line assuming an `unowned` to always have a value try to print the name of the card holder, and I got a "Execution was interrupted, reason: EXE_BREAKPOINT..."

I suppose there should not be a problem like this or there should be some kind of safety check at line `card = john.card`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Unowned references set to 'nil' when deinitialized?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491392/are-unowned-references-set-to-nil-when-deinitialized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unowned` references are useful for breaking reference cycles as an alternative to `weak` when (as the Apple Docs you referenced says) "you know that the reference will never be nil once it has been set during initialisation."

However you have fabricated an example of setting an `unowned` reference to an object which then goes out of scope making the `unowned` reference nil.

Answer (score 2):

The checked version of `unowned` is already there - it is called `weak`. That is the main difference. `unowned` is unsafe, but it can make your code clearer is some cases.

Comment: Unowned is unsafe in that it may crash your program, but the crashing behavior is well-defined. Unowned cannot cause you to access a dangling reference, for instance.